My supervisor ignores me on purpose bc I want to change the time to mark papers
I am a phd student and I am a TA for my supervisor's courses (there are two TAs in total) this term. So far I am doing well.
Recently, this course will have an exam. My supervisor asked us on Slack if we had time to go to his office at XX (time) to mark exam papers. I replied that I could at first, but after 10 minutes, I found that actually I was occupied at that time, so I immediately edited the message to ask if I could come later. He didn't reply to me before or after I edited the message.
After dozens of minutes, another TA replied that he could come, and my supervisor immediately replied to him. So I sent a new message saying that I was busy at that time. When I sent the message, I saw that my supervisor was typing in the same channel, so I was sure that he had seen my message, but he still deliberately ignored me.
In fact, I am okay if he directly says that we cannot change the time, but simply ignoring me really pisses me off.
Should I put aside my own schedule to come to mark the papers? Or should I send him an email to ask again? I am not sure if he is taming me to obey all his instructions and never dare to say no. I don't want this and I am angry with this whole meanless thing.
========= update =========
After resending an email instead of a third message on Slack, he agrees to change it to another time. I might just overthink too much.

What kind of reply were you expecting? What kind of reply did your colleague receive? So far he seems to have only asked you if you have time, not ordered you to actually come in at that time, did he?

Incredible! And after dozens of minutes you say?

@A rural reader I am not sure if you are asking my second message. It's basically the same as my first, asking if I can arrive later since I am occupied at that time.

@MisterMiyagi  He asked both of the TAs to come to his office at that time. I expect him to reply to me he can or not accept another time.

How cruel. Your advisor is obviously toxic. I suggest you contact your ombudsman ASAP and start looking for a new advisor. This type of behavior is uncalled for.

Did you suggest, in your email, a specific time when you can come in to help with the grading?

"I might just overthink too much." -- I think that is true :-) Nothing needs to be decided on the spot; give people a few hours or a day or two to figure stuff out. If you can't come one day, they might just have to figure out what other times would work for them, and that takes time. Or perhaps they just didn't have the time to figure it out right then and there. So chill out and give people the benefit of the doubt.

@Wolfgang Bangerth Thank you. I will be more patient next time. If there is no reply, I will just ask again lol.

I would suggest sending him another email.
In general I agree that not answering emails or messages is a bad practice that reflects very badly on the ignoring parties (lack of accountability, lack of basic courage, disrespect, and more). That said, many people are busy and sometimes it is hard to find the time to reply back.

Yet another email sounds like a nuisance, actually. A visit would be better.

Thanks. I will send another email and wait for his reply.

@Ashella, I'm happy to hear the email message I suggested helped at the end.

First, relax. Professors have hundred and one things demanding their attention at any given time and your assumption that you supervisor "ignores you on purpose" seems like an unlikely explanation. Perhaps he just got distracted and upon seeing that the other TA can come at a specified time, he was content that he will have enough help.
If your supervisor continues to not react to your message, I wouldn't overthink it. I would wait till I can see them face-to-face, maybe you see them in a corridor or if you can, pop into their office, and ask again if it's okay that you come to mark the exams at a different time.

Thank you for your reply. It was solved after I sent another email. I guess I indeed overthink it.
